# How to solve this solvable sextic equation by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

When I was studying the Dedekind Eta function, I encountered the following solvable equation by radical. I want to know **what its radical solution is**? What software is available to find the radical solution to such an equation?

\begin{align*}
&x^6-1080352x^5+177422336x^4-11962091216x^3\\
&\quad-5159822304x^2+4846058241024x+99474414071824= 0
\end{align*}

I tried the Maple software, which can solve some quintic equations, but for this problem it did not give a satisfactory result.

[Maple code]:

```
_EnvExplicit := true:
solve(x^5 + 10/13*x + 3/13, x);
```

[Magma code]:

```
R := RationalField(); 
R < x > := PolynomialRing(R); 
f := 99474414071824 + 4846058241024*x - 5159822304*x^2 
     - 11962091216*x^3 +  177422336*x^4 - 1080352*x^5 + x^6; 
G := GaloisGroup(f); 
print G;
GroupName(G: TeX:=true);
IsSolvable(G);
```

**Update**

Thanks for the answer from ahulpke

\begin{align*}
x_1&=\sqrt[3]{j\big(2\sqrt{11}i\big)}\\
&=\frac{52(10388+3131 \sqrt{11})}{3}\\
&\qquad+\frac{\rho_1(3 \sqrt{33}-17)^{1/3}}{6}
+\frac{\rho_2(17+3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3}}{6}\\
\rho_1&=(710362+602351 \sqrt{3}+214267 \sqrt{11}+181574 \sqrt{33}\,)\\
\rho_2&=(602351 \sqrt{3}+181574 \sqrt{33}-710362-214267 \sqrt{11})\\
\end{align*}

where $x_1$ satisfies the original sixth degree equation.

Comment: That the galois group is solvable does not mean that it is easy to solve the equation by radicals.

Comment: You might be interested in [an old blog post of mine](https://grossack.site/2021/08/06/cyclic-extensions.html) where I talk about how to solve polynomials by radicals with galois theory. I only showed the cyclic case explicitly, with a planned part 2 to come where we iterate the cyclic case to handle all solvable polynomials.... But I never got around to writing it. This will at least tell you how to solve these things in the abstract (though maybe you already know how to do this in the abstract). I have no idea how well the included code will fare against coefficients as big as yours, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the degree is not a prime power, the Galois group must be imprimitive, so it will be possible to find a proper subfield, and thus reduce the problem to smaller degree.

Here, since the Galois group is of type $S_3\times 2$, there will be a subfield of degree 2 (as well as one of degree 3).

I'm sure Maple and Magma have functionality for subfields, but I don't know the function names. (I used the function `DecomPoly` in GAP.)

This finds a subfield defined by
$$
x^2-329352742732719398000x+127120572141496598311785398863851411856
$$
which (looking at the discriminant) is the same as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$.

Over this subfield, your polynomial factors into
$$
x^3+(162812\sqrt{11}-540176)x^2+(4145648\sqrt{11}-13733928)x+(43818996\sqrt{11}-145673000)
$$
(and its Galois conjugate). This being ternary polynomials, one can use the standard formula.

Comment: In W.Mathematica code `Factor[99474414071824 + 4846058241024 x - 5159822304 x^2 - 11962091216 x^3 + 177422336 x^4 - 1080352 x^5 + x^6, Extension -> Sqrt[11]]`.

Answer (score 4):

**I. Sextic**

This particular solvable sextic $f(x)$ is special in two ways. First, since,

$$x_1=\sqrt[3]{j\big(2\sqrt{11}i\big)} = 1080187.758\dots$$

where $j(\tau)$ is the *j-function*, then,

$$e^{4\pi\sqrt{11}}=x_1^3-744.000000000000156\dots$$

and $e^{4\pi\sqrt{11}}-x_1^3$ is a bit closer to the integer $744$ than the more familiar *Ramanujan's constant* when $d=163$.

Second, as pointed out by ahulpke, $f(x)$ has *both* a deg-$2$ subfield (involving $\sqrt{11}$) and a deg-$3$ subfield. He didn't mention it, but this deg-$3$ subfield involves a rather famous number, namely the ***tribonacci constant***, the root of $t^3-t^2-t-1 = 0$. We can express $x_1$ in terms of this constant.

Given the $8$th power $u = t^8,$ define,

$$A = \frac{225 + 3518u + 225u^{2}}8\\
B = \frac{-2215 - 17058u + 1801u^{2}}{16\sqrt{11}}$$

Then the two real roots of the sextic are,

$$x_1=\sqrt[3]{j\left(2\sqrt{-11}\right)} = A+B = 1080187.758\dots$$
$$x_2=\sqrt[3]{j\left(2\sqrt{-\tfrac{1}{11}}\right)} = A-B = 32.4772\dots\qquad$$

hence an alternative way to express the roots in terms of radicals.

---

**II. Decic**

We can use the same method for other values of the $j$-function. The OP also discusses $x = \sqrt[3]{j\big(\sqrt{-74}\big)}$ which is a root of a deg-$10$ with ***large*** coefficients I gave in the comments below. To solve this, we use another constant, the real root $z$ of,

$$-61378 + 74425z - 56136z^2 + 6718z^3 - 2046z^4 + z^5 = 0$$

a quintic discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4783669/4781), and which also involves an $8$th power. Using this real root $z$, define,

$$\alpha = 8z^2+2z-16\\[6pt]
\beta = 2(4z-1)\sqrt{z^2-4}$$

Then the two real roots of the decic are,

$$x_1=\sqrt[3]{j\left(\sqrt{-74}\right)} = \alpha + \beta \approx 6.6763 \times 10^7$$
$$x_2=\sqrt[3]{j\left(\sqrt{-\tfrac{4}{74}}\right)} = \alpha - \beta \approx 8170.896844\; $$

**P.S.** Note that $z^2-4$ is a *near-square*,

$$z^2-4 = 37\left(\frac{2044274 - 3558075z + 466583z^2 - 202457z^3 + 99z^4}{37\times209152}\right)^2$$

If substituted into $\beta$, what remains as a square root is $\sqrt{37},\,$ just like the $\sqrt{11}$ in the sextic case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don’t know if this method can solve $j^{1/3}(\sqrt{-74}\>\!)$, though the minimal polynomial of the Weber-f function is obtained. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778936

Comment: @Eufisky The class number is $h(-74) = 10$ so $x = j^{1/3}\big(\sqrt{-74}\big)$ is a _solvable_ deg-$10$ equation, namely, $${615629953118233965887488 + 317222930221555706757120x + 59447014954413364281344x^2 + 2490653633095245234176x^3 + 
 166936790857906802688x^4 + 6074260303878686720x^5 + 114794959762763008x^6 + 434315611484160x^7 + 490626836656x^8 - 
 66770904x^9 + x^{10} = 0}$$ To express this in radicals will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Eufisky Actually, the method still applies. That sextic was special since it has both a deg-$2$ and deg-$3$ subfield, and you can factor it over either one. Similarly, the decic above has both a deg-$2$ and deg-$5$ subfield, and again, you can factor it over either one. You'll probably meet this double feature when the  j-function is a root of an equation of deg-$2p$ for some prime $p$.