# How to determine the minimal polynomial of the higher power of the Weber f function?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, class-field-theory

There is a certain theorem that guarantees that the function value of the higher power of the Weber f function is an algebraic integer

\begin{align*}
x\stackrel{?}{=}\mathfrak{f}^8(\tau)=\left(\frac{\eta\big(\frac{1+\tau}{2}\big)}{\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi\,\!i}{48}\right)\eta \left(\tau\right) }\right)^8
\end{align*}

where $\tau=\sqrt{-74}$.

I can't confirm whether the following polynomial is its minimum polynomial. Is there any algebraic verification method?

```
  (x^10 - 8184*x^9 + 107568*x^8 
 - 4116480*x^7 + 24214784*x^6 
 - 190388224*x^5 + 387436544*x^4
 - 1053818880*x^3 + 440598528*x^2 
 - 536346624*x + 1048576)
```

Ref:

[https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfaw/classinv.pdf](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasfaw/classinv.pdf)

[https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~ybilu/algant/documents/theses/Sotakova.pdf](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/%7Eybilu/algant/documents/theses/Sotakova.pdf)

Comment: That degree ten polynomial is almost **certainly** not satisfied by the $x$ computed from the Weber function.

Comment: @Somos Yes, you are correct. The decic root is related to the _second_ Weber function as $x = \mathfrak{f}_1(\sqrt{-74})^8$, not to the first Weber function as the OP assumed. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Comment has been modified to an answer.*)

**I. Weber functions**

There are in fact  ***three*** [Weber modular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_modular_function),

\begin{align}
\mathfrak{f}(\tau) &= \frac{\eta\big(\frac{1+\tau}{2}\big)}{\exp\left(\frac{2 \pi\,\!i}{48}\right)\,\eta\left(\tau\right)}\\[4pt]
\mathfrak{f}_1(\tau) &= \frac{\eta\big(\frac{\tau}{2}\big)}{\eta\left(\tau\right)}\\[4pt]
\mathfrak{f}_2(\tau) &= \frac{\sqrt2\,\eta\big(2\tau\big)}{\quad\eta\left(\tau\right)}
\end{align}

There are three because the $24$th powers of these (with the proper sign) are the three roots of the simple cubic,

$$j(\tau) = \frac{(u-16)^3}y$$

where $j(\tau)$ is the *j-function* and the three roots are $u = \mathfrak{f}(\tau)^{24},\, -\mathfrak{f}_1(\tau)^{24},\, -\mathfrak{f}_2(\tau)^{24}.$ Or,

$$\sqrt[3]{j(\tau)} = \frac{v^3-16}v\quad$$

and the three roots are $v = \mathfrak{f}(\tau)^{8},\, -\mathfrak{f}_1(\tau)^{8},\, -\mathfrak{f}_2(\tau)^{8}.$ The first two can be quite close numerically. For example,

\begin{align}
\mathfrak{f}(\sqrt{-74})^8 &= 8170.896840743\dots\\
\mathfrak{f}_1(\sqrt{-74})^8 &= 8170.896840503\dots
\end{align}

Compare to the larger real root $x$ of the OP's decic,

$$\qquad\qquad x= 8170.896840503\dots$$

Therefore the decic root should be equated to the ***second*** Weber function as $\color{blue}{x = \mathfrak{f}_1(\sqrt{-74})^8},$ and which can be tested correct for hundreds of decimal digits.

---

**II. The decic**

Also, there are several clues that the decic is not some random equation. First, using the transformation, $x\to 4y$, it can be simplified to the *palindromic*,

$$1 - 2046y + 6723y^2 - 64320y^3 + 94589y^4 - 185926y^5 + 94589y^6 - 64320y^7 + 6723y^8 - 2046y^9 + y^{10} = 0$$

Let $y+\frac1y = z$, and this can be further simplified to,

$$-61378 + 74425z - 56136z^2 + 6718z^3 - 2046z^4 + z^5 = 0$$

which has square discriminant $d = 2^{46}\times7^6\times652783^2\times\color{red}{74^2}$.

Second, this quintic has transitive group of order $10$, hence is *solvable in radicals*. That is not surprising since it involves the Weber modular function $\mathfrak{f}_1(\sqrt{-74})$.

Comment: @Eufisky I changed my comment to an answer. Upon more investigation, I realized the decic was for the _second_ Weber function, not to the first Weber function.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. These two values ​​are too close, and it is really easy for people to make mistakes.

Comment: @Eufisky You're welcome. The notation for the three Weber functions is also unfortunate. They should have used subscripts $(0,1,2)$ so it is clear which of the three is being discussed. **P.S.** I'm glad I came across this question and [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4783469/4781) on the deg-$6$. It made me find a way to solve certain $j(\tau)$ of deg-$2p$ for prime $p$ in a uniform manner.

Comment: I sent you an email using the email address you left on your MSE homepage. I want to find more special values of $j^{1/3}(\tau)$ together.